# Amazon Lex "slots" for alphanumeric values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bots, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have simple ask, how do I create a Amazon Lex slot for Alphanumeric values.

So far I have tried -

> - **AMAZON.Number**: only takes decimal numbers
> - **AMAZON.PostalAdress**: takes
>     everything except numbers
> - **Custom Slot with no values**: Only numbers

Is there any way to create a slot which takes alphanumeric values?

Thanks

Comment: is your issue resolved ??

Comment: No, looks like this is how it is designed :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom slot type.

Remember you don't need to enumerate all possible values, just provide enough training data so patterns match. Try giving it around 20-30 values and see if that's enough to train the slot type.

Comment: I tried that but the issue is, it learns the pattern. For example - adding "a1b" and combinations matches anything with first character second digit and third character BUT it does not match first character second character and third number or a string with more then 3 characters, like, "cf22". Writing all combinations for infinite length is practically impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular datatype to take alphanumberic values.

**AMAZON.NUMBER:** accepts only numbers

**AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME:** accepts only letters

As part of creating a chatbot in Amazon Lex, I have used **AMAZON.Movie** to accept both letters and numbers(alphanumberic values) it worked for me. As movie name can have alphanumberic values (Ex: The Incredibles2). I hope it works for you too.

Comment: That's a nice idea. Although I am not working on that project anymore but I'll keep this in mind.